# Not able to store data in a private member variable from a const member function - FIX8 c++

Tags: c++11, pthreads, fix8

This is my header :

```
class my_router_client : public FIX8::my::mine_Router {

private:
    mine_session_client& _session;
    mutable std::vector<std::string> vSymbolList;

public:
    my_router_client(mine_session_client& session) : _session(session) {}

    virtual bool operator() (const FIX8::my::SecurityList *msg) const;
    void sendToServer(FIX8::Message *); 
    void logout();
    void itertool() const;
    };
```

I am trying to save the data obtained from security list response to the vSymbolList vector. After handling security response I am trying to iterate through the vector by itertool method. But every time I end up with an empty vector. I tried printing the contents of the vector inside securitylist response function

```
virtual bool operator() (const FIX8::CX::SecurityList *msg) const;
```

and I am able to print the contents. Is it some kind of race condition inside threads?

this is the security list response handler

```
bool cx_router_client::operator() (const CX::SecurityList *msg) const
{
    GroupBase *dad(msg->find_group< CX::SecurityList::NoRelatedSym >());
    if (dad) {
        for (size_t cnt(0); cnt < dad->size(); ++cnt) {
            CX::Symbol symbol;
            MessageBase *details(dad->get_element(cnt));
            details->get(symbol);
            string ss; 
            ss = symbol();
            vSymbolList.push_back(ss);
//          cout << "at :: :: " << vSymbolList[cnt] << endl;

        }   
        cout << "no of symbol : " << vSymbolList.size() << endl;
        hypersleep<h_seconds>(1);
    }   

    return true;
}
```

This is the itertool method :

```
void my_router_client::itertool() const
{
    cout << "symbol list vector size inside itertool:: " << vSymbolList.size() << endl;

    stringstream ss; 
    ss << this_thread::get_id();
    uint64_t id = stoull(ss.str());
    cout << "Thread ID #### " << id << endl;

    vector<string>::iterator it = this->vSymbolList.begin();
    while (it != vSymbolList.end()) {
        cout << *it << endl;
        it++;
    }
}
```

This is how I use the them in main :

```
int main()
{
  const string conf_file("myfix_client.xml");

  unique_ptr<ClientSessionBase> mc(new ClientSession<mine_session_client>(my::ctx(), conf_file, "DLD1"));

  mc->start(false, next_send, next_receive, mc->session_ptr()->get_login_parameters()._davi());

  hypersleep<h_seconds>(1);

  my_router_client *test = new my_router_client(static_cast< mine_session_client& > (*mc->session_ptr()));

  hypersleep<h_seconds>(1);

  test->sendToServer(makeSecurityListRequest());

  hypersleep<h_seconds>(1);

  test->itertool();
  while(1);
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong in the code you've shown. The problem is with `itertool()` (which, I can't help but notice, you have not shown), or with the calling code. E.g. are you sure you are calling `itertool()` on the same instance that `operator()` is being called on? Print the value of `this` pointer in both, to confirm.

Comment: I created a fix8 tag for you.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik : this is kind of confusing as I am getting different 'this' eg : (0x276ff18 ) for operator() methods and (0x2718810) for other methods including sendToServer() and itertool(). I have added       "virtual bool operator() (const FIX8::CX::TradingSessionStatus *msg) const; " just for testing which also returned same this value as other operator() ie . 0x276ff18

Comment: Add a copy constructor to `my_router_client`, put a breakpoint on it, try to figure out where and why a copy gets created. Alternatively, it's possible that there's some kind of pointer casting bug, and a bogus pointer gets cast to `my_router_client` and a method called on it (though it would be a rare coincidence that a wild pointer like this would appear to work, and not crash immediately). Note that I know nothing at all about FIX8, I'm just going by the code you've shown and your description of symptoms.